# Função em JavaScript se torna "undefined" no addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Pergunta reformulada: estou tentando criar uma caixa de diálogo para o usuário, porém estou tendo um erro descrito como `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` quando clico no botão **Fechar** gerado pelo código.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jh3funk2/

O código é este:

```
    /** Dialog **/

    var Dialog = function(name, width)
    {
        // Cria frame do dialog
        var dlgFrame = document.createElement('div');
        dlgFrame.id = name;
        dlgFrame.style.display = 'none';
        dlgFrame.setAttribute("data-dialog", name);

        // Cria o container para os componentes
        var dlgContainer = document.createElement('div');
        dlgContainer.style.width = width;
        dlgContainer.setAttribute("data-dialog-width", width);

        // Cria espaço para o título
        var dlgTitle = document.createElement('div');
        dlgTitle.setAttribute("data-dialog-title", name);

        // Cria espaço para os botões
        var dlgButton = document.createElement('div');
        dlgButton.setAttribute('data-dialog-buttons', name);

        // Monta os componentes
        dlgContainer.appendChild(dlgTitle);
        dlgContainer.appendChild(dlgButton);
        dlgFrame.appendChild(dlgContainer);
        document.body.appendChild(dlgFrame);

        // Cria as variáveis
        this.dlg = document.querySelector('[data-dialog="'+name+'"]');
        this.title = document.querySelector('[data-dialog-title="'+name+'"]');
        this.buttons = document.querySelector('[data-dialog-buttons="'+name+'"]');
    }

    Dialog.prototype.show = function(display)
    {
        this.dlg.style.display = display || "flex";   
    };

    Dialog.prototype.close = function()
    {
        this.dlg.style.display = 'none';
    };

    Dialog.prototype.setTitle = function(title)
    {
        this.title.innerHTML = title;
    }

    Dialog.prototype.addButton = function(text, callback)
    {
        // Cria os elementos
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        var text = document.createTextNode(text);

        // Define o texto e o evento
        button.appendChild(text);
        button.addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            // todo: verificação do typeof
            callback();
        });

        this.buttons.appendChild(button);   
    }

    /** Controlador **/

    appController = function()
    {
        this.confirmarSaida;
    };

    appController.prototype.init = function()
    {
        this.confirmarSaida = new Dialog('confirmarSaidaDlg', '10vw');
        this.confirmarSaida.setTitle('Deseja sair do sistema?');
        this.confirmarSaida.addButton('Fechar', this.confirmarSaida.close);
        this.confirmarSaida.show();
    };

    window.onload = function()
    {
        appController = new appController();
        appController.init();
    };
```

Já testei as seguintes soluções, mas não funcionaram:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490448/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-into-an-event-handler
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803195/addeventlistener-and-the-scope-of-this

Não pretendo usar qualquer biblioteca, é um código para aprendizado.

Como fazer com que ao clicar no botão, o dialog seja fechado com a função `close`? Vale lembrar que também irei passar outros callbacks para o botão, não somente o `this.close()`;

Comment: Ao executar seu código eu não obtive o erro que você relatou, eu obtive o seguinte erro, Uncaught TypeError: this.confirmarSaida.setTitle is not a function(…), isso não aconteceu com você também?

Comment: Esta faltando os métodos *setTitle* e *setButton*;

Comment: Verificando eu notei que não tem um propriedade chamada *this.dlg*, o que estaria gerando este erro. Você deve defini-la. creio que seja `this.dlg = dlgFrame`, mas você deve verificar

Comment: Vocês tem razão, eu esqueci boa parte do código ao passar para o StackOverflow, irei modificar a pergunta, obrigado.

Comment: Estou votando pra fechar, para não gerar respostas hipotéticas, ate que possa ser reaberta com a situação real.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert a pergunta já está corrigida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A razão para este erro é que ao utilizar `addEventListener` o `this` é alterado para o quem disparou o evento ou seja o `button`.
Assim o `this` que se encontra na função `close` não é o que você espera `Dialog`, e sim `Button`.

Para revolver este problema você pode usar o método [*call*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) e setar uma variável anterior ao escopo do `addEventListener`, que sera usada no método.

```
Dialog.prototype.addButton = function(text, callback)
{
    // Cria os elementos
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    var text = document.createTextNode(text);

    var self = this;

    // Define o texto e o evento
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        // todo: verificação do typeof
        callback.call(self);
    });

    this.buttons.appendChild(button);   
}
```

Perguntas relacionadas

- [O que é e como funciona o contexto no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8975/14213)
- ["this" uma referencia confiavel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119384/14213)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Guilherme, muito obrigado, irei ler as perguntas relacionadas que postou.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, pelo o que nos conversamos nos comentarios da sua pergunta, eu creio que seja algo relacionado ao fato de você não definir dlg, dentro da função Dialog, sendo assim tente modificar o código para o seguinte:

```
var Dialog = function(name, width)
{
    //código adicionado
    this.dlg = {};

    // Cria frame do dialog
    var dlgFrame = document.createElement('div');
    dlgFrame.id = name;
    dlgFrame.setAttribute("data-dialog", name);

    // Cria o container para os componentes
    var dlgContainer = document.createElement('div');
    dlgContainer.style.width = width;
    dlgContainer.setAttribute("data-dialog-width", width);

    // Cria espaço para o título
    var dlgTitle = document.createElement('div');
    dlgTitle.setAttribute("data-dialog-title", name);

    // Cria espaço para os botões
    var dlgButton = document.createElement('div');
    dlgButton.setAttribute('data-dialog-buttons', name);

    // Cria espaço para os botões
    var dlgButton = document.createElement('div');
    dlgButton.setAttribute('data-dialog-buttons', name);

    // Monta os componentes
    dlgContainer.appendChild(dlgTitle);
    dlgContainer.appendChild(dlgButton);
    dlgFrame.appendChild(dlgContainer);
    document.body.appendChild(dlgFrame);
}
```

Comment: Você tem razão, eu esqueci boa parte do código ao passar para o StackOverflow, irei modificar a pergunta, obrigado.

Comment: Mas o problema era esse mesmo? resolveu?

Comment: Isso não vai resolve o problema pois setar `this.dlg = {}` apenas o torna um objeto, ele vai continuar não tendo o método *style* necessário no  `Dialog.prototype.show`

Comment: Ok, mas ele falou que no código dele, ele tem esse método, apenas esqueceu de colocar, sendo assim pode funcionar.

Comment: Corrigi a pergunta com o código completo