# Como não perder o "this" do objeto atual

Tags: javascript, escopo-de-variáveis

Eu já havia feito uma [pergunta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119384/14213), contudo desta vez estou com um problema um pouco mais complexo :

```js
ObjectTest1 = (function(){
  
  var init = function(){
      this.callback = null;
  }
  
  init.prototype = {
    setCallback : function(callback){
      this.callback = callback; // O CALLBACK DEFINIDO AQUI É init.prototype.methodTest2 PERTENCENTE AO ObjectTest2
    },
    applyCallback : function(){
      if(typeof this.callback == 'function'){
        this.callback();  // CHAMADA NORMAL DE init.prototype.methodTest2 DO OBJETO ObjectTest2
      }
    }
  }

  return init;
}());

ObjectTest2 = (function(){
  
  var init = function(){}

  init.prototype = {
    methodTest1 : function(){
      console.log('methodTest1');
    },
    methodTest2 : function(){
      console.log('methodTest2');
      var self = this; // AQUI this PASSA A SER ObjectTest1 MESMO EU NÃO TENDO USADO .call OU .apply
      if(typeof self.methodTest1 != 'undefined'){ // ESTE METODO NÃO EXISTE NO ObjectTest1 POIS ELE É DO ObjectTest2
        self.methodTest1();
      }else{
        console.log('ERROR');
      }
    }
  }
  var newInit = new init;
  return newInit;
}());

var o = new ObjectTest1();
o.setCallback(ObjectTest2.methodTest2);
o.applyCallback();
```

#### Duvida

- Porque o ***this*** foi alterado se eu fiz uma chamada normal do método?
- Como eu posso fazer para não perder a referencia ***this*** do objeto que estou atualmente?

#### Resumo

Eu instancie o `ObjectTest1` e setei como *callback* um método do `ObjectTest2` que por sua vez ao ser executado deveria chamar um outro método de si próprio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, eu não sei ainda o porquê de no Javascript funcionar assim, mas eu já tive muitos problemas com isso, quando tento, por exemplo, simplesmente passar a referência da função como callback.

Vou mostrar abaixo um dos casos onde tive esse problema.

Veja:

```js
var els = ['#id', '#id2'].map(document.querySelector);
```

O erro retornado é:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)

Parece ser um erro relacionado ao contexto em que o `querySelector` foi aplicado. Ou seja, não foi invocado com o contexto de `document`, e sim de `Array`.

## Uso do Bind

A solução foi usar o método `bind`, que definirá um escopo para o callback passado. Mesmo que esse callback entre em outro escopo, ele será executado no contexto em que foi passado em `bind`.

No caso do exemplo, o problema aciam foi resolvido assim:

```js
 var els = ['#id', '#id2'].map(document.querySelector.bind(document))
```

## O seu caso

No seu caso, eu utilizei o `bind` quando passo o `callback` para a função `ObjectTest1.setCallback`.

Veja:

```js
ObjectTest1 = (function(){
  
  var init = function(){
      this.callback = null;
  }
  
  init.prototype = {
    setCallback : function(callback){
      this.callback = callback; // O CALLBACK DEFINIDO AQUI É init.prototype.methodTest2 PERTENCENTE AO ObjectTest2
    },
    applyCallback : function(){
      if(typeof this.callback == 'function'){
        this.callback();  // CHAMADA NORMAL DE init.prototype.methodTest2 DO OBJETO ObjectTest2
      }
    }
  }

  return init;
}());

ObjectTest2 = (function(){
  
  var init = function(){}

  init.prototype = {
    methodTest1 : function(){
      console.log('methodTest1');
    },
    methodTest2 : function(){
      console.log('methodTest2');
      var self = this; // AQUI this PASSA A SER ObjectTest1 MESMO EU NÃO TENDO USADO .call OU .apply
      if(typeof self.methodTest1 != 'undefined'){ // ESTE METODO NÃO EXISTE NO ObjectTest1 POIS ELE É DO ObjectTest2
        self.methodTest1();
      }else{
        console.log('ERROR');
      }
    }
  }
  var newInit = new init;
  return newInit;
}());

var o = new ObjectTest1();
o.setCallback(ObjectTest2.methodTest2.bind(ObjectTest2));
o.applyCallback();
```

## Solução em jQuery

Apenas a nível de informação adicional, no jQuery é possível resolver esse problema usando `$.proxy`.

Leitura recomendada:

- [Why are certain function calls termed “illegal invocations” in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

Não há nada de inesperado no seu código. `this` está apontando, corretamente, para *o contexto do objeto que invocou o método onde `this` foi utilizado*.

O seu stack é o seguinte:

```
new ObjectTest1()         <- contexto
.applyCallback()          <- função
[ObjectTest2.methodTest2] <- função
var self = this;          <- this: referência do contexto ObjectTest1()
```

ECMAScript 5 introduziu a palavra-chave [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), que você pode utilizar quando chamando uma função para que escopo e corpo sejam preservados.

No seu caso, para preservar o contexto, preserve-o com uma referência (o motivo de várias implementações JS possuírem uma linha `var self = this;`.)

Fontes e mais informações:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score 6):

Regra: uma função corre no mesmo contexto de quem a chamou.

Há ferramentas para modificar isso. O `new`, como tu usaste, mas também `.call(contexto)`, `.bind(contexto)` e `.apply(contexto)`.

Contudo neste caso o que falha é que tens `var self = this;` dentro da função. É tarde demais, pois aí o contexto já é defenido por quem chamou, ou seja o `Objeto1`.

Neste caso parece-me que a solução mais simples é passar o `self = this` para dentro do `init`, forçando assim o contexto desejado no momento em que crias uma nova instância:

```
ObjectTest2 = (function() {
    var self;
    var init = function() {
        self = this;
    }
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0o5wqgpz/

Comment: Realmente é um resposta valida e revolve meu problema perfeitamente, contudo creio ser mais aplicável a resposta do @wallace, pois caso eu queira alterar para `return init;` cada instancia teria que ter seu próprio escopo de `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Pode não ser muito prático, mas o this está sempre associado a uma **chamada**, não a uma declaração de função (tentaram melhorar um pouco isso com as funções com flecha =>, que seguem outras regras)

No seu código

```
var o = new ObjectTest1();
o.setCallback(ObjectTest2.methodTest2); // Aqui você perdeu o this
o.applyCallback(); // Aqui você chamou (indiretamente) usando “o” como this
```

Na segunda linha você jogou fora o this, já que a função não conhece o seu this, ele é setado apenas na chamada.

Na terceira linha você usou o objeto “o” como this, ainda que indiretamente.

As possibilidades para o this são:

1. method() → não tem this (estou simplificando...)
2. obj.method() → this é obj
3. new Method() → cria um novo this.
4. .call() e .apply() → permitem escolher o this dinamicamente
5. .bind() → permite fixar um this a uma função para que ela não “esqueça” a quem pertence.

Então, qual é a solução? O jeito mais simples na minha opinião é criar uma nova função que não precise de this:

```
o.setCallback(function () {
    return ObjectTest2.methodTest2();
});
```

Mas usar o bind (ver as outras respostas, o uso deve ser algo como: `ObjectTest2.methodTest2.bind(ObjectTest2)`) tem o mesmo efeito. Eu me acostumei a fazer sem bind porque há um tempo atrás nem todos os navegadores suportavam.

Comment: interessante ver que nesse escopo também funcione. +1.