# É possível atribuir uma função nativa para uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Um exemplo hipotético...

```js
let _ = document.querySelector;

_(".hello").style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<div class="hello">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No javascript, os métodos de objeto em Javascript têm um contexto. Quando você usa algum objeto nativo e tenta atribuir um método deste a uma variável, para chamá-la posteriormente, você vai receber um *Illegal Invocation*. Isso porque essa função perderá o contexto original que lhe fora atribuído e receberá por padrão o contexto global, que no caso é `window`, conforme se lê nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743608/3096922) do SOEN.

Para solucionar isso, você deve informar explicitamente o contexto em que a função vai ser chamada, através do método `bind`.

```js
let _ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

_(".hello").style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<div class="hello">Olá, mundo</div>
```

O contexto de `querySelector` é `document`. Assim sendo, ao atribuir o valor do método a uma variável, é preciso informar através do `bind`.

Outra forma (menos elegante) seria usando o método `call`:

```
  _.call(document, ".hello").style.color = "red"
```

Ou ainda usar uma função anônima ou arrow funcion para resolver o problema:

```js
let _ = (...args) => document.querySelector(...args);

_(".hello").style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<div class="hello">Olá, mundo</div>
```

Não vou alongar demais, porque creio que tem parte da explicação aqui:

- [Como não perder o "this" do objeto atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151201/como-n%C3%A3o-perder-o-this-do-objeto-atual/151227#151227)

Comment: Obrigado pelo resposta! mas tenho mais uma dúvida, digamos eu queira usar o querySelector sem o document, por exemplo _("#minhaDiv").querySelector("input"); no código ao lado o querySelector funcionaria como um find do jquery, e uso muito em meu projeto, saberia como fazer um bind disso também?

Comment: Acho que não entendi muito bem. Poderia deixar um exemplo?